# Sending email on port 587 works using telnet but not in C# code

Tags: c#, email

I am trying to send email on port 587 via a HostGator account on a **Windows Server 2008 R2** machine. It all works if I check things via TELNET:

[image]

I then do the same thing via a C# .NET application:

```
    public class EMailSendViaHostgator
{
    private readonly string _Password;
    private readonly string _Sender;

    public EMailSendViaHostgator()
    {
        _Sender = "";
        _Password = "";
    }

    public void SendMail(string aRecipient, string aSubject, string aMessage)
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("mail.willswelldone.com.au")
        {
            Port = 587,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false
        };

        NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(_Sender, _Password);
        client.EnableSsl = false;
        client.Credentials = credentials;

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(_Sender.Trim(), aRecipient.Trim())
        {
            Subject = aSubject,
            Body = aMessage
        };
        client.Send(mail);

        MessageBox.Show("Message Sent");
    }
}



private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EMailSendViaHostgator sendMail = new EMailSendViaHostgator();
            sendMail.SendMail("someone@there.com", "Some Subject!", "This is the message.");
        }
```

NOTE: The username/password and recipient email address have been omitted for security purposes.

I run the above code in a WinForms app and get no exception and the "Message Sent" dialog box however the email never arrives. If I run the exact same application on my development Win 7 box the email arrives without an issue.

Getting HostGator to check their email logs is proving to be problematic, but as I am not getting any exception I am assuming that the SmtpClient is successfully connecting on port 587 and sending the message.

So any ideas why SmtpClient is failing on Windows Server 2008 R2 but works fine on my Windows 7 box using exactly the same credentials etc.

All ideas and suggestions appreciated.

Comment: everything is looking good. did you deployed it in Server or just running in VS?  if yes put a break point near `client.Send(Mail)`. and check whether it takes sometime to go to next line. Usually it will take 5-15 secs to verify connection and send mail.

Comment: Its a WinForms application and I cannot debug it on the server. The delay between  the button click and the message dialog coming up seems about the same.

Comment: Do you see an error? Anything in the 'eventvwr'?

Comment: Nothing at all in the event viewer (Application and Security)

Comment: Given it is running on Windows Server, have you tried to run the app As Administrator so that it has elevated privileges? I see that you are using an Admin cmd prompt.

Comment: Yep, running as Administrator does not make any difference. Account I am logged into is also part of the Admistrators group.